# Google Play Service Is Not Woking On Emulator

Tags: android

I am trying to test a Simple Map application on Emulator.I also Installed the Following Apks on emulator `com.google.android.gms-1.apk` and `com.android.vending-1.apk` and `Google Play Store 4110.apk` and Here is Preview of My emulator

**`device`**  `3.2 HVGA SLIER(320480*)`
**`TARGER`**  `Google APIs Api Level 15`
**`internal storage`** `200 mib`
**`sd card`** `500 mb`
Any One Help Me to Get Out of This Issue Plz i am trying Since two days But Map is not loading On emulator

Comment: why dont you test it on a device ? Do you get any log cat warnings or errors ?

Comment: check out this blogpost: http://piotrbuda.eu/2012/05/installing-google-play-on-android-emulator.html

Comment: check your code in real device is working ?if working then please put your code because i am trying to display google map but unable to set google map.

Comment: Sir I checked But I Dnt Understand Whats Happening there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need any of the below to test Google Play Services .apk:

1. A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.2 or higher and
   includes Google Play Store.
2. The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs
   platform based on **Android 4.2.2** or higher.

Yours is 4.0.3

Answer (score 1):

You should test your map application on a real device. I would suggest you to test it on a real device.

There is a work around. Drawing from the below link. I have not tested it. But you can give it a try.

http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527

Download com.android.vending.apk from

http://www.mediafire.com/download/pxpjfkveemq29qk/com.android.vending.apk

Download com.google.android.gms.apk from

http://www.mediafire.com/download/zn8wna5wf4ek5le/com.google.android.gms.apk

Open eclipse and the AVD Manager and create an AVD with the following configuration:

[image]

Start the AVD and wait for it to finish booting, next open you command prompt and install
both apk’s using the “adb install” command. for example:

To install use the following command

adb install com.android.vending.apk

You should receive “SUCCESS” message at the end of the installation process (that may take some time).

When you finish installing both apk files, close the AVD and reopen it. Now you should see a map in your application when you use the AVD instead of this annoying message.

**Note** : This will work only if you are using google-play-service lib revision #4 in your application (and workspace). If you have already updated google-play-services using the SDK Manager to the latest version (Currently: revision #6) you will receive an error telling you that you that the google-play-services used by your application is too old and needs to be updated:

Further you can check this blog by Emil Adz.

http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435

Answer (score 0):

There's a new emulator called [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com) that supports play store and google play services