# Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to run Google Map's sample project on emulator. Now I have an error:

> Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above

How can I resolve that problem?

Comment: you will have to use a device that supports open gl es 2.0. that's the fix

Comment: [check this previous post for answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360588/google-play-service-is-not-woking-on-emulator/17360681#17360681)

Comment: can you give me an example of the devices that support open gl 2.0?

Comment: "can you give me an example of the devices that support open gl 2.0?" -- pretty much anything made in 2010 or beyond. Presently, 99.8% of devices support OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: Where can i see if the device support it? I use platform 4.2.2 on my emulator

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue running with an emulator. I fixed by editing my emulator in **AVD Manager**, at **Emulator Options** checking the box for **Use Host GPU**.

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps API v2 has a bug. See here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5440

As linked by Tony in comments above there may be a workaround if you can get hold of and replace the appropriate apk files on the device. Or you can just wait ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add feature  required for  OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 
To work with Google Maps , just add the following code in your project's AndroidManifest.xml file before application tag:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

May this will help you :)