# Google map api it’s not work in API27 emulator

Tags: android

I can’t use google map with android emulator in API27.
When I open the app, it show nothing ,just google logo show at left-down corner.
But it work in API26 and lower version emulator with the same code.
I know many people have the same problem too.
But there is no solution to fix this problem.
I hope there is any one had fixed it and tell me what’s going on....
Thanks

https://upload.cc/i/4C65rs.png

```
E/Google Maps Android API: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
```

Comment: Any logs ? do you have PlayServices installed on API27 emulator ?

Comment: I suggest adding an image of the results when you open the app and offer a sample of your code.

Comment: @ADM There is my error in Logcat...but I use the same emulator and same setting just different API version. 
Yes, I install the PlayServices and update it to the v11.9.51

Comment: Have a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378942/google-maps-android-api-v2-only-supports-devices-with-opengl-es-2-0-and-above) if already not .

Comment: @Dom Hi, I have uploaded the image. And the code just use Googlemap Activity by Android Studio. And I did't change any thing but API key.

Comment: @ADM Hi, thanks for your answer. I already try the way the method in that site.....But there is no help about my issue....

Comment: @ADM Is the googlemap work normally on your API27 emulator? I can use google map api on my API26 emulator,I just know how can't I use google map api on API27 emulator..

Comment: Try enable Use Host GPU in emulator setting.If still won't work then pls test on a real device with API27 to make sure its emulator issue or something else .