# Google Map Is Not Working On Emulator with AVD supporting Google API 4.2.2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm getting the following logcat message when trying to run a application supporting google map. 
**"Google map android api v2 supports devices with opengl ES2.0 and above"**

In [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360588/google-play-service-is-not-woking-on-emulator/17360681#17360681)
it is answered that application using google services run in "Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher."

Though I'm using an AVD with Google API 4.2.2, I could not able to make it work.

Your help is highly appreciated since I don't have real device to test it right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no errors other than this "google map android api v2 supports devices with opengl ES2.0 and above" in logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps API v2 has a bug. See here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5440

Answer (score 1):

Maps are working in Google API 4.3 and Api Level 18, Please Update your SDK